# Clang Error: Reference to NSUTF8StringEncoding is ambiguous

Tags: xcode, xctest, nsstringencoding

I am trying to create unit tests using the new XCTest framework introduced in Xcode 5. I have a line in one of my test cases that looks like this:

`XCTAssertEqual([self.client stringEncoding], NSUTF8StringEncoding, …);`

When I try to run my tests, Xcode spits out this error: "Reference to NSUTF8StringEncoding is ambiguous." I can get the test to work by changing the above line to this:

`XCTAssertEqual([self.client stringEncoding], (NSStringEncoding) 4, …);`

(This works because 4 is the value of `NSUTF8StringEncoding`.) This also happens when I assign `NSUTF8StringEncoding` to a local variable and use it in the `XCTAssertEqual()` call instead. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: That code works for me. If you put NSUTF8StringEncoding back in the function, and command-click on it, what do you see?

Comment: @bneely: When I Command-click on the NSUTF8StringEncoding, I am taken directly to its declaration at `NSString.h` line 40. It still doesn’t compile.

Comment: Which frameworks are you linking with in your unit test target? Which header(s) are you including in the unit test implementation file (the .m file)?

Comment: I’m #including `<Foundation/Foundation.h>` and `<AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>` (the latter is the framework that I’m testing). I am linking against the Cocoa, AFNetworking, and XCTest frameworks. Still won’t work.

Comment: When you search your project for NSUTF8StringEncoding via the Find Navigator, what do you see?

Comment: Have you tried (NSStringEncoding)NSUTF8StringEncoding in your test?

Comment: @bneely: I see only references to the symbol in comments, framework code, and once in the unit test that is giving me trouble. Casting the value to type `NSStringEncoding` makes no difference.

Comment: I'm stumped here. This may be an Apple bug. If you're determined to work around this, you could try changing the test to `XCTAssertTrue(NSUTF8StringEncoding == [self.client stringEncoding], @"");`

Comment: I get this as well, but it goes away when I actually compile and run the tests so its more of an annoyance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178109/xctassertequal-error-3-is-not-equal-to-3 ?

Comment: I have also started to get this with one of my build targets after I tweaked the minimum deployment target and SDK version to match between it and the target whose product acts as the bundle loader for the test suite. Stuck :-(

Answer (score 0):

Please import below framework in your file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```