# XCTAssertEqual: How to compare NSDates?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ios7, xctest

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
XCTAssertEqual([[store selectedDate] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate], [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);
```

This gives me the error message:

```
(([[store selectedDate] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]) equal to ([date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate])) failed: 
("405290648.294") is not equal to ("405290648.294")
```

I had previous a similar problem with Integers, which had to solved by casting it to `NSUInteger` as described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19178109/xctassertequal-error-3-is-not-equal-to-3)

But I couldn't figure out how to solve this with NSDate objects / doubles (as in this case).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

use `XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy` to compare floating numbers

```
XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy([[store selectedDate] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate], [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate], 0.001);
```

Comment: Thank you ! In Swift you can now use this without the "WithAccuracy" part. Just add the "accuracy" parameter at the end.

Answer (score 6):

In earlier Swift you needed to use this:

```
let receivedDateTimeInterval = receivedDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
let expectedDateTimeInterval = expectedDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy(receivedDateTimeInterval, expectedDateTimeInterval, accuracy: 0.001)
```

Now you can lose the "WithAccuracy" part:

```
XCTAssertEqual(receivedDateTimeInterval, expectedDateTimeInterval, accuracy: 0.001)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, and should be sufficient for the test.

```
XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy([refDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate], [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate],0.00001,@"");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the two `double` values probably differ at one more significant digit than is displayed in the assertion (perhaps `405290648.2942` vs. `405290648.2941`).

If you don't care about fractional seconds in the comparison then use `round` or `floor` on both values or cast both to `long long` for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a simple test you can see that the values are different. The fact that they look the same in the assertion output is most likely to do with the way the log output is built.

```
NSDate *date  = [NSDate date];
NSDate *date2 = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"%f %f", [date2 timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate], [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]); //=> 405292099.192900 405292099.192899

XCTAssertEqual([date2 timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate], [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);
```

You should use `XCTAssertEqualWithAccuracy` as these are essentially `double` values